# Android get Packets from WiFi results

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

Is it possible to get the raw packet from wifi scan results more specifically I would need the timestamp when packet was created or sent from the Access Point.

I would like to compare the time of when packet was sent from the router and time of when it was received to calculate it's travel time and how it's affected by barriers like say walls.

Comment: Did you able to solve it?

Comment: @Muthu I found out it's possible using NDK however it's incredibly messy and the results you get on paper seem usable but in practice not so much. My idea was to calculate time required for singal to traven between two devices and use that to calculate the distance but this was incredibly flawed thinking. Since a small delay (and there are many) will cause massive variations in calculated distance.